# How do you make YouTube videos adapt to smaller screen sizes?

Tags: responsive-design

When you Share a video from YouTube it asks you for a size, in px.  How do you then make that video scale as the screen gets smaller?

Comment: Look up responsive embed css, fitVids.js etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty straight forward you just need to add width: 100% on the enclosing div or to the iframe and it will resize automatically. If you add height 100% it will squash the video pretty bad so from my experience just adding width is enough.